# Under what conditions the globally optimal solution and solution obtained by step-by-step optimization are the same?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

More specifically, I have a problem where it is hard to find the optimal solution w.r.t all the parameters together, so I solve it w.r.t one parameter at a time. In each step, I either use the optimal value of other parameters obtained from the previous step or just keep them as variables to be optimized later. I can not prove the convexity / concavity of the problem but can show the objective function to be monotone w.r.t all the parameters. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1293761)

Comment: Thanks David. It is exactly what I am already doing, but the answer doesn't specify when will the solution be equal to the global one? Is there any theorem / result that I can refer to ?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing that and not [coordinate descent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent)? Also, if the objective is monotone then it can't have an optimum except at the boundary, can it?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453831/optimization-of-a-function-of-two-variables