# Partial minimization of function over variables

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

In Boyd and Vandenberghe's textbook on Convex Optimization, is claimed that:

> We always have $$ \underset{x,y}{\text{inf}\; f(x, y)} = \underset{x}{\text{inf}}\;\tilde{f}(x) $$
>   where $$ \tilde{f}(x) = \text{inf}_y\;f(x, y).$$ In other words, we can always minimize a function by
>   first minimizing over some of the variables, and then minimizing over the remaining
>   ones.

My question is the following (since it is unclear to me from the context): does this applies only to convex functions or to every function?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453831/optimization-of-a-function-of-two-variables